# Biblatex changed APA 7 formatting

Tags: biblatex, apa7

This week I encountered a strange change in the way Biblatex formats certain references in APA 7 style. Since I didn't change anything in the way the document is coded and formatted it baffles me on the how and why of this change.

I am using TexStudio 4.0 with the MikTex distribution on Windows 10 21H1. The installed packages are updated to the most recent ones. My biblatex call in the TeX file is:

```
\usepackage[style=apa,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{hb_specialist.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
```

I am using Zotero to provide the hb_specialist.bib file.

When I check the Zotero APA 7 style presentation I get the correct layout (see screenshot):
[image: Zotero style check]

In an earlier version of the document I am writing the formatting in the bibliography was correct. A screenshot of that document:
[image: References in 2021-08-24 version]

But as I compiled the same file yesterday and today I got a different formatting of the same references. See this last screenshot:
[image: References in 2021-09-29]

I am not aware of any changes in package updates that could influence this behaviour.

What I would like to know is where to look for clues on this behaviour in log files and of course how to remedy this formatting.

A MWE showing the faulty formatting is below. The entries in filecontents are copied from the zorero hb_specialist.bib file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}

%----- taal/font pakketten
\usepackage[english,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}

\usepackage[
typeface=gfsartemisia,
sanstypeface=tgheros:scale:0.93,
textcomp=dontload,
]{typeface}

\usepackage{hyperref,csquotes}

%----- bibliografie -----
\usepackage[style=apa,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

%----- Bronvermelding -----
\addbibresource{files/\jobname.bib}
\urlstyle{sf}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{files/\jobname.bib}
@online{ruhl2016,
    type = {Edutainment},
    title = {Intelligence: Definition, Theories and Testing.},
    author = {Ruhl, Charlotte},
    date = {2016-07-16},
    url = {https://www.simplypsychology.org/intelligence.html},
    urldate = {2021-04-11},
    abstract = {Take-home Messages Defining and classifying intelligence is extremely complicated. Theories of intelligence range from having one general intelligence (g), to certain primary mental abilities, and to multiple category-specific intelligences. Following the creation of the Binet-Simon scale in the early 1900s, intelligence tests, now referred to as intelligence quotient (IQ) tests, are the most widely-known and used measure for determining an individual’s intelligence. Although these tests are generally reliable and valid tools, they do have their flaws as they lack cultural specificity and can evoke stereotype threat and self-fulfilling prophecies. IQ scores are typically normally distributed, meaning that 95\% of the population has IQ scores between 70 and 130. However, there are some extreme examples of people with scores far exceeding 130 or far below 70.},
    langid = {english},
    organization = {{SymplyPsychology}}
}
@unpublished{vandasler2020,
    type = {Powerpoint},
    title = {Levenlang hoogbegaafd?},
    author = {Van Dasler, Hanneke},
    date = {2020-10-06},
    abstract = {Inleidende presentatie over begaafdheid bij de opleiding tot HB Specialist van de Hogeschool Windesheim.},
    eventtitle = {Opleiding HB Specialist},
    langid = {Nederlands},
    venue = {{Hogeschool Windesheim, Zwolle}},
    keywords = {gifted education,special educational needs,theoretical framework},
    file = {D\:\\Datamap\\Zotero\\storage\\QM3S7RLQ\\Van Dasler - 2020 - Levenlang hoogbegaafd.pdf}
}
@thesis{vangerven2021,
    title = {Raising the Bar. {{The}} Competencies of Specialists in Gifted Education},
    author = {Van Gerven, Eleonoor},
    date = {2021},
    institution = {{Universiteit van Hasselt}},
    location = {{Hasselt, België}},
    langid = {english},
    pagetotal = {509},
    annotation = {ISBN 978-94-0361-786-2}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
    Van Dasler (\citeyear{vandasler2020}) betrekt in haar presentatie het werk van Van Gerven. Van Gerven heeft onlangs haar proefschrift gepresenteerd, waarin ze een overzicht geeft van de ontwikkeling van begaafdheidsonderwijs in Nederland \parencite{vangerven2021}. Intelligentie is een construct waar geen consensus over bestaat: zie \cite{ruhl2016}.
    
    \section*{Bronnen}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=bibempty]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll look at the actual problem in a minute, but note that you should remove most `biblatex` options like `sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,` if you want true APA style, since `style=apa,` takes care of the correct settings (in particular of `sorting`). `Van Dasler (\citeyear{vandasler2020})` should ideally be `\Textcite{vandasler2020}` or if the handling of "van" is not satisfactory at least `Van Dasler \parencite*{vandasler2020}`

Comment: I checked with the earliest version of `biblatex-apa` that implements 7th-edition APA style and could not reproduce the output of the "before" screenshot. Note that the "before" screenshot does not fully align with the Zotero screenshot. ...

Comment: ... I am no expert in APA style, but a short look at the examples in https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples suggests that there should be no ISBN at all and that "SymplyPsychology" in the online reference should be upright and not in brackets (https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/webpage-website-references). That's pretty much what the "after" screenshot shows if you remove the `annotation` field with the ISBN (ISBNs should go into the `isbn` field).

Comment: Thanks for your comments @moewe . The ISBN is entered in an extra field in Zotero and shouldn't be in the APA entry as a thesis usually hasn't an ISBN number. But this one does .. The other entries were present in all versions, but to my knowledge they don't interfere with the APA notation. I am going to check on removing them. As for correct APA entry: there should be square brackets around [powerpoint] not curved ones. Also there should be [proefschrift] added to the Van Gerven entry. It was there, now it isn't anymore. That's what baffles me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not manage to produce the output from the "before" screenshot of the PDF with even the oldest version of `biblatex-apa` that implements 7th-edition APA style.

Assuming you actually want APA style, the "after" screenshot is fairly close to what you need. But there is some room for improvement

- APA style does not use ISBNs in general and does not need ISBNs for theses. Putting the ISBN into the `annotation` field is also a bad move from a general `biblatex` perspective, since the field `isbn` is dedicated to holding the ISBN.
- PowerPoint slides are added slightly differently in `biblatex-apa`. If you have less common types, the example file https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib can be of great help. `biblatex-apa` uses `@image` here (see example below).
- APA style usually does not include the URL access date. The examples only do that if the "contents of a page are designed to change over time". You'll have to make the judgement call if that is the case for `ruhl2016` or not. https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/webpage-website-references

I'd probably come up with something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[english,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\urlstyle{sf}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{dutch}{
  powerpoint = {PowerPoint slides},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{ruhl2016,
  type         = {Edutainment},
  title        = {Intelligence: Definition, Theories and Testing},
  author       = {Ruhl, Charlotte},
  date         = {2016-07-16},
  url          = {https://www.simplypsychology.org/intelligence.html},
  urldate      = {2021-04-11},
  langid       = {english},
  organization = {SymplyPsychology},
}
@image{vandasler2020,
  entrysubtype = {powerpoint},
  title        = {Levenlang hoogbegaafd?},
  author       = {Van Dasler, Hanneke},
  date         = {2020-10-06},
  eventtitle   = {Opleiding HB Specialist},
  langid       = {Nederlands},
  publisher    = {Hogeschool Windesheim, Zwolle},
  keywords     = {gifted education,special educational needs,theoretical framework},
}
@phdthesis{vangerven2021,
  title       = {Raising the Bar},
  subtitle    = {The Competencies of Specialists in Gifted Education},
  author      = {Van Gerven, Eleonoor},
  date        = {2021},
  institution = {Universiteit van Hasselt},
  location    = {Hasselt, België},
  langid      = {english},
  pagetotal   = {509},
  isbn        = {978-94-0361-786-2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \Textcite{vandasler2020} betrekt in haar presentatie het werk van Van Gerven.
  \Citeauthor{vangerven2021} heeft onlangs haar proefschrift gepresenteerd,
  waarin ze een overzicht geeft van de ontwikkeling van 
  begaafdheidsonderwijs in Nederland \parencite{vangerven2021}.
  Intelligentie is een construct waar geen consensus over bestaat: zie \cite{ruhl2016}.

  \printbibliography[title=Bronnen]
\end{document}
```

[image: Ruhl, C. (2016, juli 16). Intelligence: Definition, theories and testing. SymplyPsychology. Verkregen 11 april 2021, van https://www.simplypsychology.org/intelligence.html Van Dasler, H. (2020, oktober 6). Levenlang hoogbegaafd? [PowerPoint slides]. Hogeschool Windesheim, Zwolle. Van Gerven, E. (2021). Raising the bar: The competencies of specialists in gifted education (proefschrift). Universiteit van Hasselt. Hasselt, Belgi¨ e.]

Comment: Thanks again @moewe. I accepted your answer and advice. I am currently reviewing my entries in Zotero and changing some of them. I still get curly brackets instead of square ones even when using your example. Must be something locally in my installation, I guess ..